# How to resize the detailsView after cross button is clicked after the closing view is hidden?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

[![when the cross button is clicked, the closingView is hidden.][1]][1]

import UIKit
import IBAnimatable

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var closingView: AnimatableView!
@IBOutlet weak var detailsView: AnimatableView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnClose: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var closeViewBtn: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var isCloseButtonTapped = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func btnCloseAction(_ sender: Any) {
    isCloseButtonTapped = !isCloseButtonTapped
    if isCloseButtonTapped{
        closingView.isHidden = true
    }else{
        //
    }
}
```

}
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpH2A.png

Answer (score 0):

You can add closingView and detailsView inside a UIStackView. When the closingView is hidden the detailsView will fill up the entire space in the parent UIStackView.